# Mysql mysql_num_rows($result); alternatives

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a quicker query of counting how many rows there are using a WHERE statement?
The current query I use in PHP is:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE id FROM users WHERE user = '$tnuser'");
$total = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

The table engine is InnoDB and ID is primary key and user is indexed. This query is ran 300+ a second so any performance gain would be good. The total count is always changing and users are deleted/added very often.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually its faster to use the aggregate functions of SQL to count something. You could for example try

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE user = '$tnuser'
```

Comment: It has improved most queries from 500 ms to 200 ms Thank you!

Comment: That still sounds like a lot for something which should be a quick index reference; check if you have proper indexes set up on your table with EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) ...;

Comment: @fiskfisk sry I meant it improved the script itself with php by 300 seconds by adding that. It caused mysql to use less cpu by 20% at peak.

Comment: Oh yes, it's way better than what you had before, but a simple count against an index should not take 200ms under most circumstances.